# Using atoi not able to accept char type - any way around this?

Tags: c

The following code fails because `atoi()` requires a `char *` and I'm only passing a `char`. I want to store the value of only the first digit. Any idea how I can do this?

```
int main () {
  char a[]= "123";
  int b = atoi(a[0]);
  printf("%d",b);
}
```

Here's the exact error message:

```
division.c:9:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing
      'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
      [-Wint-conversion]
  int b = atoi(a[0]);
           ^~~~
           &
```

Comment: `atoi()` is intended to convert a null-terminated string of characters; as such, it won't work with a single character.  If the compiler allowed your call, the function would interpret the character value as an address, which would not lead to happiness.  You've been shown how to deal with a single digit — arguably, you should check that it _is_ a digit before applying the `a[0] - '0'` conversion.  Of course, `atoi()` will simply return 0 if the string is a string but isn't recognizable as a number; functions such as `strtol()` tell you about whether a value was converted, or was too big, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, a single character is not a string as `atoi()` requires.

If you just want the value of the single digit, you can do it like this:

```
int b = (a[0] - '0');
```

Comment: @Charana `char`s are treated just like any numeral type such as `int`, `short`, `long`, etc., and the mathematics are what you expect. `'0' + 5 == '5'`, `'a' + 3 == 'd'`, and finally, `'7' - '0' == 7`.

Comment: @Charana slightly off topic, there are a lot of cool tricks you can do just by knowing how to manipulate `char`s mathematically. For example, to test if a `char` is an upper-case letter, you could just `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')`

Comment: @Charana: Each character is equal to a numeric value. Consider the case where `a[0]` is '0': `'0' - '0' = 0`. The value of '1' is one more than '0', so `'1' - '0' = 1`, and so on.